# Socket.io can't get rid of "io is not defined" error

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webmatrix

Can't get socket.io to work and always got error `ReferenceError: io is not defined`

Server code:

```
express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io')
app = express();

var io = socket.listen(app);

app.get('/room', function (req, res) {
res.render('room.ejs')
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) { 
    console.log('Client connected...')
    });

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 17336);
```

Client code:

```
<script src="localhost:17336/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:17336')</script>
```

Here's directory structure of my site:
(making it in WebMatrix)

```
Site
  |__iisnode
  |__node_modules
       |__.bin
       |__ejs
       |__express 
       |__socket.io
  |__public
  |__views
       |__room.ejs (Client code is here)
  |__favicon.ico
  |__robots.txt
  |__server.js (Server code is here)
  |__web.config
```

Comment: In the docs it says: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` but you changed it...

Comment: Yes, cos it's not working that way, i searched some questions and do as suggested

Comment: If that is not working, then your problem described is not the problem you face... You tried `var socket = io.connect(); // TIP: .connect with no args does auto-discovery`?

Comment: Not working, and, well, I think problem is not here, atleast yet, cos it just can't define `io`, therefore can't find this socket.io.js for some reason.

Comment: This error is getting in the browser (looking in firebug in mozilla)

Comment: And bout server errors, how can I look at it? Working thrue WebMatrix...

Comment: I am sure the problem is there.... try `var io = socket.listen(80);`

Comment: What is your node,express version ?

Comment: Express is 3.2.4 version
I leave io.connect() and tryed `var io = socket.listen(80);`  not working...

Answer (score 1):

This is because `localhost:17336/socket.io/socket.io.js` is not available. I am guessing your socket.io server is not starting because you are using Express 2.0 syntax, but have Express 3.0 installed.

Express 3 requires that you instantiate a `http.Server` to attach socket.io to first. Here is how I do it :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: sadly  io is not defined again

Comment: I left out `server.listen(17336);` Can you try it. Don't put `process.env.PORT` because it can create confusion. On client put the same port `http://localhost:17336/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: well server.listen or app.listen is not working if i delete `process.env.PORT`, even cant start any page, even can't start a page, it says 
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error

Comment: With `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 17336);` it's kinda some progress but `"IIS Express Worker Process" has stopped working` thrown when i trying to access my site from browser. Firebug says `Firefox can't connect to server ws://localhost:17336/socket.io/1/websocket/Q2Q6ecHHmpdjSSPLDifP.  this.websocket = new Socket(this.prepareUrl() + query);`

Comment: I think the port is being taken from `process.env.PORT`, which is what you should listen for on browser. Do `console.log(process.env.PORT);` to find out what the value is. Then replace 17336 with that in your browser.

Comment: When i start site in WebMatrix it automagicaly starts http://localhost:17336 that's why i placed this 17336 everywhere

Comment: And about console log, just want to check it out, i nned to use it in
`app.get('/room', function (req, res) {
res.render('room.ejs')
console.log(process.env.PORT);
});`? if like that, hten i see no messages except errors in firebug console

Comment: OK, one question which browser(s) are you testing on ? Tell the version.

Comment: What is your IIS version ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30996/discussion-between-sinnersmile-and-user568109)

Comment: To anyone who intrested, it seems that i need 8.0 version of IIS, in 7 and 7.5 that is in my WebMatrix websockets are not supported

Comment: Oh, it seems that websockets supported only in Win8 ahhh...
seems that I need to install new system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about socket.io, but taking the error message literally, it appears that `localhost:17336/socket.io/socket.io.js` is not importing the symbol `io` into the client. Then the next line is impossible because `io` is not yet defined.

You should open that `socket.io.js` file in your browser and read it, to make sure it really is defining a variable called `io`.

Comment: Yes, but this way of pointing to this js is working to most of ppl, and i even can't open it in browser, on this way it says `cannot GET`
i found `socket.io.js` in `socket.io/lib/socket.io.js`, but even if i try `http://localhost:17336/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js` in browser it's still `cannot GET`.